# Relationship between correlation and coskewness

Tags: correlation, skewness

If C is a NxN correlation matrix of a N variables and s is vector of N univariate standard deviations for those variables, we can compute covariance matrix by:

S = s'sC

Is there a way to compute coskewness matrix with given correlation matrix and vector of univariate skewnesses? Same for cokurtosis...

Comment: Welcome to CV. Analysis of multivariate skewness and kurtosis have been proposed beginning with Mardia (1970) *Measures of multivariate skewness and kurtosis with applications* and extended, more recently, by Kollo in this article ... http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X08000626

Comment: Thanks for a reference but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution there. I would appreciate any help because I'm struggling with the problem for a long time now...